# Output of dist() with more than 3 dimensional matrix in R

Tags: r, matrix, distance

I'm new to R.
I can't figure out the meaning of dist() out.

I understand the following. Because the euclidean distance between (1,3) and (2,4) is √2

```
> x = matrix(1:4, 2, 2)

> x
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    1    3
[2,]    2    4

> dist(x)
         1
2 1.414214
```

But how should I see the output for more than 3 dimensional matrix?

```
> x=matrix(1:25, 5,5)

> x
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]    1    6   11   16   21
[2,]    2    7   12   17   22
[3,]    3    8   13   18   23
[4,]    4    9   14   19   24
[5,]    5   10   15   20   25

> dist(x)
         1        2        3        4
2 2.236068
3 4.472136 2.236068
4 6.708204 4.472136 2.236068
5 8.944272 6.708204 4.472136 2.236068
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The number in the cell in column named "1" and row named "2" is the distance between the first and second rows of your data.

So `2.236068` is the distance between the vectors  `c(1,6,11,16,21)` and `c(2,7,12,17,22)` (rows 1 and 2),
   `4.472136` is the distance between vectors `c(1,6,11,16,21)` and `c(3,8,13,18,23)` (rows 1 and 3) and so on.